# Concat two strings with same FK

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have the following tables in mysql

```
table payment_enum(
id int PK,
name text,
category_id int FK to category
)

table category(
id int PK,
category_name text
)
```

What i want is: in payment_enum its posible to have two column with difference names but with the same category_id
For example :

```
select * from payment_enum 
pk   name  category_id
1    'first'  2
2    'second' 2
```

And the category with PK = 2 has name 'laptops'
Is it possible to use query that will produce the following result

```
category_name category_PK enum_names
laptops        2            first,second
```

Pseudo query

```
select c.name,c.pk, e.name as (concat (e.name,concat(',',select e2.name where e2.name like e.name from payment_enum as e2)))
 from category as c and payment_enum as e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select c.name as category_name ,c.pk as category_PK , GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) as enum_names from
(select * from category) as c
left JOIN
(select * from payment_enum) as p
on c.id = p.category_id GROUP BY  c.name,c.pk
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `group_concat` instead of `concat`

```
select c.name,group_concat(e.name) as enum_names
from category as c
left join payment_enum as e on c.id = e.category_id
group by c.name
```